# Special dot-product

Tags: products

I have been wondering if the following dot product definition for the $n$-coordinate vectors $a$ and $b$ has a name:
$$<a\backslash b> = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i*b_{n-i+1},$$
rather than the classical dot product:
$$<a\backslash b> = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i*b_{i}.$$
Did you already seen it use somewhere?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should it be $$<a\backslash b> = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i*b_{n-i+1}?$$

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: you could write as $\langle a | X b \rangle$, where $X$ is antidiagonal unit matrix... maybe you can interpret this as scalar product in a space with metric $X$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can diagonalize this bilinear form so that it becomes the sum of $p$ squares minus the sum of $q$ squares where $p$ and $q$ are $n/2$ rounded up and down, respectively. This is called a quadratic form of signature $(p,q)$, and the space in which this norm is the inner product is denoted $\mathbb R^{p,q}$. For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group

Answer (score 1):

After a reindexing, I would call what you have a [(discrete) circular convolution](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=54kTgFg5IVgC&pg=PA289&dq=%22circular%20convolution%22).